# how to push an array inside an array with nested nested loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

With the following code, I want to push an array inside the `weeks` array if `i` is `<=` to the value of each element in that array.

```
const weeks = [];
const daysInWeek = [];
numberOfDays = 35;

for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfDays; i ++) {
  if (i % 7 === 0){
    weeks.push(i)
  }
  // output [7, 14, 21, 28, 35]
  for (logic here...) {
    daysInWeek.push([?])
  }
}
```

I would like `daysInWeek` to look something like this :

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15,......], ...]
```

It is the first time I work with nested loops and I can't really grasp the idea and therefor I am unsure how to use the second loop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new array inside of the `if (i % 7 === 0){` statement. That array is going to be created for every week and is going to hold your days.

Now start the second loop by subtracting `6` from the current value of `i`. `i` will always be a multitude of 7. So by subtracting 6 you get the first day in that week. Store that result in `j`.

Then for the evaluation part of the loop. Check if `j` is **equal or lower** than `i`. We never want to go higher than the last day in the current week. Also check if `j` is **equal or lower** than `numberOfDays`. You don't want to add more days than you indicated.

Add each day to the days array. Then after the loop add the days array to `daysInWeek`. Now you've got this nested array structure.

```js
const weeks = [];
const daysInWeek = [];
numberOfDays = 35;

for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfDays; i++) {
  if (i % 7 === 0) {
    weeks.push(i);
    
    const days = [];
    
    for (let j = i - 6; j <= i && j <= numberOfDays; j++) {
      days.push(j);
    }
    
    daysInWeek.push(days);
  }  
}

console.log(daysInWeek);
```

Comment: that's a great answer! Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is wrong. Please try this also.

Within a single loop we can create both all arrays and add them together like this.

```
const weeks = [];
    const daysInWeek = [];
    numberOfDays = 35;
    
    for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfDays; i ++) {
      const weekid = parseInt(((i-1)/7));  // used i-1 because in the loop i started as 1. if we use i/7 we loose a day record from the first week. Test it.
      if(!weeks.includes(weekid) ){
        weeks.push(weekid);
      }
      let tempArray = [];
    
      if(daysInWeek[weekid] === undefined){
        daysInWeek[weekid] = [];
      }
      daysInWeek[weekid].push(i);
    
    }
    console.log(daysInWeek);
```

Answer (score 0):

Math.floor((i - 1) / 7) give you the key of the table to push your days

```
<script type="text/javascript">
const weeks = [];
const daysInWeek = [[]];
numberOfDays = 35;

for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfDays; i ++) {
  if (i % 7 === 0){
    weeks.push(i)
    daysInWeek.push([])
  }
  daysInWeek[Math.floor((i - 1) / 7)].push(i)
}

console.log(daysInWeek);
</script>
```